# Disabled SIP, but still can't make changes?

Tags: macos, security, catalina, permission, sip

Disabled SIP, but still can't make changes:

```
sh-3.2# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),1(dae……
sh-3.2# mkdir PAH-en
mkdir: PAH-en: Read-only file system
sh-3.2# csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.
sh-3.2# pwd
/System/Library/Input Methods/PressAndHold.app/Contents/PlugIns/PAH_Extension.appex/Contents/Resources
```

## go up several levels (no ACLs or xattrs on intermediates)

```
sh-3.2# pwd
/System/Library
sh-3.2# cd ..;ls -lae@ | head
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@   8 root  wheel   256 Oct 12 16:17 .
    com.apple.rootless     0 
 0: group:everyone deny delete
sh-3.2# cd ..;ls -lae@ | head
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@   8 root  wheel   256 Oct 12 16:17 .
    com.apple.rootless     0 
 0: group:everyone deny delete
drwxr-xr-x   22 root  admin   704 Jan 30 11:54 ..
-rw-r--r--    1 root  wheel     0 Aug 25 17:26 .localized
drwxr-xr-x   39 root  wheel  1248 Oct 12 16:16 Applications
drwxr-xr-x    5 root  wheel   160 Oct 12 16:11 DriverKit
drwxr-xr-x  116 root  wheel  3712 Oct 18 00:55 Library
drwxr-xr-x    3 root  wheel    96 Aug 24 15:20 Volumes
sh-3.2# pwd
/System
```

So the `xattr` says I cannot delete anything, but why can't I create something?

For that matter, if SIP only prevents delete when enabled, why is `sudo mkdir` rejected here when SIP is on?

Comment: Thanks for the edit—sorry for forgetting to do that!

Comment: Yep, that’s pretty much the same question.  Too bad the suggestions don’t work very well.